# Rabbitmq topic misunderstanding

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a queue D4 in my test rabbitmq environment.
I want use a topic exchange to publish messages to the D4 queue.
In web management console I've bind messages with routing key K to queue D4.
But my messages do not deliver to D4 queue.
All is ok when I change topic to direct exchange.
What is wrong with my code?

```
ExchangeName = <<"custom.topic">>,   
ExchangeType = <<"topic">>,  
Key = <<"K">>,
Msg = <<"123">>,
{ok, Connection} = amqp_connection:start
    (#amqp_params_network{username = <<"guest">>, password = <<"guest">>, host = "192.168.1.1"}),
{ok, Channel} = amqp_connection:open_channel(Connection),
#'exchange.declare_ok'{} = 
    amqp_channel:call(Channel, #'exchange.declare'{exchange=ExchangeName, durable=true, type = ExchangeType}),
amqp_channel:call(Channel, #'basic.publish'{routing_key = Key}, #amqp_msg{props = #'P_basic'{delivery_mode=2}, payload = Msg}),
```

Answer (score 0):

I found error myself.

amqp_channel:call(Channel, #'basic.publish'{**exchange= ExchangeName**,routing_key = Key}, #amqp_msg{props = #'P_basic'{delivery_mode=2}, payload = Msg})